Clarification on Lowenheim-Skolem
I am trying to read about the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem (on my own and am a beginner so bear with me), which says that for any infinite $\mathcal{L}$-model $A$ with $X \subseteq A$, there is a Skolem Hull $H(X)$ of $X$ which is an elementary submodel of $A$, and which satisfies $X \subseteq H(X) \subseteq A$ and $|X| \leq |H(X)| \leq |X| \cdot |\mathcal{L}| \cdot \aleph_0$.
Now, I read as well that if ZFC is consistent, then there is a countable model of ZFC by the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem. I would like to clarify something about this Corollary.

Suppose that ZFC is consistent and $X$ is countable, then $H(X)$ is also countable. However, it is possible that for some $Z \in H(X)$, we have $|Z|=\aleph_0$, so that for some set $Y$, we have $|Y| = 2^{|Z|}$ as uncountable ... How will this satisfy the Power Set Axiom of ZFC since $Y \not \in H(X)$ with $H(X)$ being countable ...
Suppose that ZFC is consistent and $X$ is a set of finite sets. In this case, for any $Y \in H(X)$, we have $2^{|Y|}$ as countable and finite so that the Power Set Axiom holds in $H(X)$. However, we cannot satisfy the Axiom of Infinity since all sets in $H(X)$ are finite.

Any help is really appreciated.


The power set axiom, relativized to a model, says that for any set $X$ in the model, there is a set $P(X)$ in the model whose elements (according to the model) are exactly the subsets of $X$ according to the model. That last "according to the model" is important... means only the countably many subsets of $X$ in the model need to be in $P(X)$. 2) Why does every $Y\in H(X)$ have to be finite if $X$ is a set of finite sets? That doesn't make sense to me.


@spaceisdarkgreen okay thanks, just a little added question, so this means that even if $X=\aleph_0+1$, it is possible to have an $H(X)$ that is countable and yet still satisfy the power set axiom ?

What do you mean by $\aleph_0+1$? The ordinal $\omega+1$? In any event, if $X$ is countable, whether it be the empty set, $\omega+1$, or some countable set of ordinals bigger than the first inaccessible cardinal, there is a countable elementary submodel (of any given model with $X$ as a subset) with $X$ as a subset.

Maybe I should be a bit more explicit, since there seem to be several overlapping sources of confusion. If $(M,E)\models \sf ZFC,$ applying the LS theorem (say, to $\emptyset \subseteq M$) yields a countable elementary submodel $(N,E\upharpoonright N)\preceq(M,E).$ In the usual case of interest where $E=\in \upharpoonright M$, and $M$ is transitive, $N$, though countable, won't necessarily be transitive and it will generally contain some uncountable sets as elements, but its Mostowski collapse will be a countable transitive model, containing only hereditarily countable sets.

(None of that has any specific bearing on the power set axiom... but, yes, the power set axiom is a first-order statement: elementary submodels of models satisfying the power set axiom satisfy the power set axiom.)

@spaceisdarkgreen thanks a lot for all your help ... but just to press a little bit more ... suppose that infinite countable $X$ satisfies ZFC and has an infinite member $y$ s.t. $|y|=|\mathbb{N}|$. By ZFC, the powerset of $y$ (call it $P(y)$) is in the hull $H(X)$ and $|P(y)|=2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$  which is uncountable from the outside of $H(X)$ ... or are the premises that such a model $X$ with such a $y \in X$ (with $|y|=|\mathbb{N}|$) and which satisfies ZFC not possible ?

This hull part is confusing me... first off, there's generally no such thing as "the" Skolem hull. Second off, if $X$ already satisfies ZFC, is $H(X)$ not just $X$? what is the "hull" even relative to? Assuming you just mean "if $X$ is a countable (transitive?) model of ZFC and $y\in X$, then by the power set axiom, $P(y)\in X$", that's false, per my first comment. In the transitive case, the power set axiom implies $P(y)\cap X\in X,$ not necessarily $P(y) \in X.$

@spaceisdarkgreen ok please ignore the hull part so we have just $X$ as satisfying ZFC ... am thinking that if there's a $y \in X$ s.t. $|y|=|\mathbb{N}|$, then by the power set axiom, we should also have $P(y) \in X$ and $|P(y)|=2^{|\mathbb{N}|}$ so it happens that $X$ is uncountable to begin with ... is this reasoning correct ?

No, read my last two sentences (perhaps you missed my edit).

@spaceisdarkgreen oh okay thanks !

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem's_paradox
